# The value of `this` keyword of a function returned from a getter

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I found an unexpected value of *this* keyword in the following example :

```js
let x = {
    z : 10 ,
    get func1() {
        return function(v) {
            console.log(this === v);
        }
    }
}


x.func1(x)
```

The value of *this* keyword is the object *x* as if it's executed from that object, I expect only the *get function* that has *this* keyword equals to the calling object *x*

this example shows us the difference

```js
let x = {
    func2() {
        return function(v) {
            console.log(this === v);
        }
    }
}

x.func2()(x);
```

In both examples *func1* which is the getter function, and *func2* which is a method of the object, are executed from the object *x*, and the returned function is then executed. So why *this* value in the first example not equals to the global object instead of the object *x*.

Comment: Really, really interesting question. I'd never though of this wrinkle before.

Comment: "*as if it's executed from that object*" - but it **is** executed on that object, right there: `x.func1()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a **very** interesting question.

It's because the function is being called immediately on the result of a property access. So these are fundamentally equivalent:

```js
let x = {
    get func1() {
        return function(v) {
            console.log(this === v);
        };
    },
    func2(v) {
        console.log(this === v);
    }
};

x.func1(x);
x.func2(x);
```

In both cases:

1. The value of the property is read, resulting in a function reference.
2. That function is executed as part of the same property access expression.

The fact that `func1` is an accessor property and `func2` is a data property doesn't matter. It's how the value resulting from reading the property is used that matters.

Comment: I thought that the the whole expression will be evaluated to the function object and then executed. Thanks got it

Comment: @KirollosNasr Yes, it is, but in the expression  `x.func1` it keeps the reference to `x` as the context for the subsequent call, in contrast to `x.func2()` (from your question) which evaluates to a function as well but is not a member access expression.

Comment: @Bergi - I think you meant `x.func2()(x);`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I refer to the expressions inside `x.func1(x)` and `x.func2()(x)`

Comment: @Bergi yeah it has a tricky part. But now it's more clear Thanks to T.J. Crowder and you